# deploying a MERN stack project

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have a MERN [Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dSJe.png) that i have done and now i want to deploy it, the thing is i never deployed a project, so my question is : i have seen youtube videos about deploying with heroku, and my project has 3 folders ( backend(has the api requests) [backend folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTqxR.png) , frontend [Frontend folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qnp3.png) and dashboard [dashboard folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cC9J.png) ), i need my dashboard to stay on local, and the frontend to be deployed, do i need the backend folder deployed with it ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes. You have to deploy your backend in order to be accessible on the internet for your users when visiting the frontend app.

You can run your dashboard frontend locally if it doesn't have to be accessible on the internet, and you are or someone else is the only user that is going to use it.

However, don't forget to update your two frontend apps to use the production backend URL (something like `https://some-domain-name.com`) that you are going to deploy instead of the URL that you use during development (`http://localhost:<PORT>`).